# My keyboard messes up after executing my code (PYTHON)

Tags: python, keyboard

For my code I am using the import keyboard, and after I execute the code, my keyboard thinks the ctrl key is pressed down and I need to press Control again for it to realize that the key isn't pressed down.

For example when I press 'A' (without really pressing on control), it selects all (like 'Ctrl + A'), or when I press 'F', it shows me the find in page thing (like 'Ctrl + F').

Just to clarify, after I execute my code, my keyboard does this stuff that I wrote here in every program.

Example for my code:

```
import keyboard
keyboard.press('Control+S')
keyboard.write('Hello')
keyboard.press('enter')
```

I run this code on google, this part of code saves an image, names it 'Hello', and then presses enter to download it.

Comment: If you run this in an IDE, `Control+S` probably means something. Have you considered what that meaning might be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I run this code in google. Ctrl + S just saves the page.